# getting error on .p12 certification creation for blackberry web works app?

Tags: blackberry-webworks

getting this error using command prompt and using graphical tool also,
how to solve it, please help me.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen.getSelfCertificate(Lsun/security/x509/X500Name;Ljava/util/Date;J)Ljava/security/cert/X509Certificate;
at net.rim.device.codesigning.keytool.KeyTool.a(Unknown Source)
at net.rim.device.codesigning.keytool.KeyTool.if(Unknown Source)
at net.rim.device.codesigning.keytool.KeyTool.a(Unknown Source)
at net.rim.device.codesigning.keytool.KeyTool.main(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 32bit, or 64bit java jdk?  If it's 64bit, that is very likely part (if not all) of the issue.